# CompareTo and Equals methods while creating Custom Writable Data type in Mapreduce - explanation

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Working hard to learn mapreduce programming and very interested and excited as well. I came across on a blog about writing Custom Writable data types in Mapreduce. It is available at http://hadooptutorial.info/creating-custom-hadoop-writable-data-type/#comment-15753

I was able to implement this code at my end. It ran fine. But I didn't quite understand COmpareTo and Equals methods. can someone kindly explain those two methods with respect to this dataset? I know that CompareTo and Equals methods will be used during sorting phase and hashCode() during Partitioner phase. But I am having hard time understanding CompareTo and Equals  methods. Would greatly appreciate if someone tries to explain them.

Input dataset is a web log and each line in the log file is a record. The author of this program created a custom data type to read the web logs.

**Sample input dataset:**

41823   /miwttvnllumo.html  2014-03-10  12:25:44    418.233.13.412

8350    /ilyhxttpxu.html    2014-03-10  12:23:20    4.175.198.160

127248  /rr.html    2014-03-10  12:32:08    42.416.153.181

81262   /illrz.html 2014-03-10  12:25:17    203.156.137.68

705636  /tzvvxhst.html  2014-03-10  12:18:10    141.127.120.127

The output of the program shows the Ip address (the last field in the dataset above)  and number occurances in the web log dataset. The code works fine.

Here is the WebLogWritable class that implements WritableComparable Interface:

BTW I understand that by default whenever an object is created, hashCode gets generated. Because, if we save those multiple instances of that class into any collection or Arrays and if we need to order them, ordering will be done by hashCode that each object is assigned when they got created.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


 public class WebLogWritable implements WritableComparable<WebLogWritable>
 {
   private Text siteURL, reqDate, timestamp, ipaddress;
   private IntWritable reqNo;


    //Default Constructor
 public WebLogWritable() 
 {
  // System.out.println("const");
    this.siteURL = new Text();

    this.reqDate = new Text();

    this.timestamp = new Text();

    this.ipaddress = new Text();

    this.reqNo = new IntWritable();
 }

  //Custom Constructor
   public WebLogWritable(IntWritable reqno, Text url, Text rdate, Text  rtime, Text rip) 
   {

      this.siteURL = url;
      this.reqDate = rdate;
      this.timestamp = rtime;
      this.ipaddress = rip;
      this.reqNo = reqno;
   }

     //Setter method to set the values of WebLogWritable object
    public void set(IntWritable reqno, Text url, Text rdate, Text rtime, Text rip) 
    {
      this.siteURL = url;
      this.reqDate = rdate;
      this.timestamp = rtime;
      this.ipaddress = rip;
      this.reqNo = reqno;
    }

     //to get IP address from WebLog Record
     public Text getIp()
    {
      return ipaddress; 
      }

  @Override
 //overriding default readFields method. 
  //It de-serializes the byte stream data
   public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException 
  {
      ipaddress.readFields(in);
      timestamp.readFields(in);
      reqDate.readFields(in);
      reqNo.readFields(in);
      siteURL.readFields(in);
   }

  @Override
  //It serializes object data into byte stream data
   public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException 
  {
       ipaddress.write(out);
       timestamp.write(out);
       reqDate.write(out);
       reqNo.write(out);
       siteURL.write(out);
    }


   @Override
    public int compareTo(WebLogWritable o) 
   {
      // System.out.println("fdfddf");
     if (ipaddress.compareTo(o.ipaddress)==0)
     {
         return (timestamp.compareTo(o.timestamp));
     }
     else return (ipaddress.compareTo(o.ipaddress));
    }



   @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) 
  {
      if (o instanceof WebLogWritable) 
     {
         WebLogWritable other = (WebLogWritable) o;

         return ipaddress.equals(other.ipaddress) &&     timestamp.equals(other.timestamp);

       }
       return false;
     }


   @Override
   public int hashCode()
   {
      //System.out.println(ipaddress.hashCode())   ;
    return ipaddress.hashCode();
    }


   }
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? `compareTo()` orders objects by `ipaddress` first, then by `timestamp`. `equals()` is consistent with that, in that objects with same `ipaddress` and `timestamp` are considered equal. Doesn't seem that complex to understand.

Comment: Was it a dumb question ? Thats why I got -negative 1 for this question? No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of the `compareTo()` and `equals()` here is very simple, the `compareTo()` in this example starts by checking if this object's `ipaddress` is the same as the other object we are comparing to and if it is the same then the comparison is done based on the `timeStamp` value, otherwise the comparison result is determined by the value of the `ipaddress`.

The `equals()` method in this case basically states that two objects of type `WebLogWritable` are equal only and only if the `ipaddress` of this object is equal to the `ipaddress` of the other object's AND when the `timestamp` of this object is equal to the other object's `timestamp`, and that's all there is to it.

There are many resources that explain those methods in details out there, but if you still need help let me know.

Comment: Thanks much. Since I am not good at Java, It is probably little confusing for me. I will write some code in core java implementing CompareTo and Equals.  Thanks again.

Comment: @QuakeCore - Lets say the mapper emits keys of type WebLogWritable , assume 4 keys have been emitted , how many times does the compareTo method gets called ?